# What should we do when a question is vandalised by its owner?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545567/stored-procedure-to-insert-data-checking-its-existence) in the VLQ queue when I noticed that the question itself had been vandalised by its owner:

[image]

What's the appropriate thing to do here? Roll back the edit - the question itself was upvoted and had an upvoted answer so there is clearly some value to it. I couldn't decide so I left a comment and flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: Rolling back is just fine. No need for mod flagging IMO.

Comment: If it happens *again*, roll it back and then flag for mod attention.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have rolled it back, but won't flag in the future unless the rollback gets vandalised.

Comment: The only reason I can see someone doing this is that they asked a bad question and tried to delete it, only to be advised that they can't because someone has answered it. I, myself, have been in this situation, but I've just let them go (so I have some really bad questions out there that I can't delete). There should be a way to allow someone to delete a question that has answers within a certain time frame while allowing the answerers to keep their upvote points.

Comment: Say something about this too https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53586407/revisions

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Roll back, *once*.

If the user then insists and remakes the edit, there is almost no way the outcome would not be an edit war or comments clash, so only then flag for moderator attention and disengage.

Commenting is fine, but not necessary, as a non negligible portion of users that do that tend to aggressively respond to communication attempts.

Comment: Why is it wrong to call for a mod? Self-vandalism is vandalism and demonstrates a desire to be subversive. This person should be thrown off the site, or at least given a time-out.

Comment: @matt:  Mods should be called in when it's established that non-diamond moderators can't handle the situation anymore.  Vandalized posts can be dealt with by rolling back the post.  If it escalates into a rollback war, that's when you need to involve moderators, since they can actually prevent the war from continuing by locking the post, giving the user a break, etc.

Comment: @matt We do not punish desires here. We fix actions. Mods are needed only when it is no longer clear that someone's actions can continue to be fixed without diamond power support.

Comment: Or when the user vandalizes multiple posts.

Comment: @user202729: or their own question *and* [the answer they got](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53366372/revisions). OP suggested the destructive edit with a plea "plz halp me delete this", and the answerer obliged by accepting the edit. (Apologies for the double comment; Resubmitting with evidence as I have been challenged on making incredulously sounding claims ...)

Comment: I always choose to roll back *twice*, reason being [2 roll backs from the same user will trigger an auto-flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222644/394554)

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least 2,000 reputation, you should rollback the vandalism, usually no more than ***twice*** (which should trigger an automatic mod flag indicating possible rollback war).

In a room I'm frequently in, we catch [a lot of](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=few+unique+characters&room=11540) self-vandalism every day. Usually when we have a user with enough reputation to roll it back, they go and do so. We sometimes add an (automated) comment telling the OP that vandalism is not an accpeted behavior on Stack Exchange.